# String not passing to second Android activity

Tags: android, string, android-activity, android-intent

I'm trying to start a new activity in my android app, and I'm trying to pass a simple string from the first activity to the second activity. I want the string to display in a textview for now in the second activity, but it just won't work. What am I doing wrong?

The initial activity:

```
package com.amritayalur.mypowerschool;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class MyPowerSchoolActivity extends Activity {
Button buttonSubmit;
TextView TextViewTitle;
TextView TextViewDesc;
EditText EditTextURL;
String url = "";
 String str;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    buttonSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSubmit);
    TextViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTitle);
    TextViewDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewDesc);

    EditTextURL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextURL);


    //Start TextView
    TextViewTitle.setText("MyPowerSchool");


    //button listener
    buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        String url = EditTextURL.getText().toString();


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent i = new Intent( MyPowerSchoolActivity.this,
creds.class);    


            i.putExtra("pschoolurl", url);
            final int result = 1;
            startActivityForResult(i, result); 

        }

    });



}       
}
```

The second activity:

```
package com.amritayalur.mypowerschool;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class creds extends Activity {

String test;
TextView TextViewTest;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);




    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String test = intent.getExtras().getString("pschoolurl");

    TextViewTest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextViewTest);
    TextViewTest.setText(test);

}
}
```

I know the textview displays properly in the second activity; it works with any dummy text, just not the variable.

Comment: by just won't work-  Do you mean it crashes?  Displays an empty string?  What happens?

Comment: Just a blank background in the second activity. No characters are displayed by the textview.

Comment: Use `Log.i("MyPowerSchoolActivity","Url = "+url);` to see the value of 'url' before it is added to the intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You instantiate the string way too early, when creating the listener, instead, you should get it when the listener gets called:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent( MyPowerSchoolActivity.this, creds.class);    
        i.putExtra("pschoolurl", EditTextURL.getText().toString());
        // get the text here     ^^^
        final int result = 1;
        startActivityForResult(i, result); 
    }
```

BTW, please follow the naming conventions and start variables with a lower-case letter (editTextURL) it will make the code less confusing for other people (like me :) )

Comment: Fantastic! Would you mind explaining to me the problem with instantiating the string too early?

Comment: At the point you initialized it, which is when you created the listener, which is in onCreate, the editText was still empty, so you assigned an empty string to it.

Comment: Here's a link to those naming conventions:  http://source.android.com/source/code-style.html - BTW, don't stress too hard if something slips by once in a while -- For instance,  Binyamin missed the part about "treat Acronyms as words" :P  (editTextUrl)

Comment: @AlexanderLucas - got me there :)

Answer (score 0):

The value for url is getting set at instantiation time for your OnClickListener, before you have put any value into it. Try reading the value from your TextView in the body of the onClick method instead.

Answer (score 0):

Its notting wrong in your code just remove the String beside url in buttonsubmit.onclicklistener method. you dont have to startanactivity for result if u juat want to send a string from one activity to another. 
Thy this in your second activity.

```
Bundle b=getIntent().getExtras();
String url = b.getInt("pschoolurl");
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out just put this code in your onclick of first activity  Note:-> directly capture the edittext  donot save the edit text in string and then pass it ,if you will do show then string will not pass. see the below example

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent i = new Intent(this,Web.class);
    i.putExtra("epuzzle",urlenter.getText().toString());
    final int result = 1;
        startActivityForResult(i, result);
    }
```

now in second activity  put this ,Note:->   is you will try to save the passeed  string  of activity  first in to another string  in activity second  then it will not work ,you should directly pass the string to loadurl  instead of saving and passing to loadurl.

```
  Intent intent = getIntent();
   w.loadUrl(intent.getExtras().getString("epuzzle"));
   w.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

plz let me know  if it worked for you or not.