# Android passing of string to another activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Can I ask if someone knows how to pass the data entered from one activity to another activity? The string to be passed to that activity will be compared to the images in the database of the Android phone..

Here is the code sirs:

AlphabetConversion.java

```
package com.mobilebasedsignlanguage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class AlphabetConversionMenu extends Activity {

    EditText et_conv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alphaconv);

        Button alphaConv = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_alphaconv);
        et_conv = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_convtxt);

        alphaConv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {        
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String checkWord = et_conv.getText().toString();
                Bundle word = new Bundle();
                word.putString("key", checkWord);
                Intent a = new Intent(AlphabetConversionMenu.this, AlphabetCompareClass.class);
                a.putExtras(word);
                startActivity(a);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the java for the second activity

```
package com.mobilebasedsignlanguage;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AlphabetCompareClass extends Activity {

    String get;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alphabetcompare);

        Bundle gotWord = getIntent().getExtras();
        get = gotWord.getString("key");
        TextView Word = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        Word.setText(get);

        for(int x = 0; x > gotWord.getString("key").length(); x++){
            //if(gotWord.getString("key").charAt(0) == "SELECT * from " + TABLE_CONTACTS)
            // Get Image from the Database
            // Set it on Image View
            // set timer 2 secs 
         }
    };

}
```

The comments in the second activity I think I don't know how to code that. Really need someones help. Thank you very much.

Comment: check this..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9321543/string-not-passing-to-second-android-activity?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to save information on the shared preferences?

Allows you you to save "key-value".

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 1):

First, you should put it into extras in the first activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlphabetCompareClass.class);
intent.putExtra("STRING_KEY", yourString);
```

In the second activity you can take it from extras:

```
String yourString = getIntent().getExtras().getString("STRING_KEY");
```

Or you can use shared preferences to store information. It's more convenient if you should save info for more than one activity change.

Answer (score 1):

try this on AlphabetConversion.java

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String checkWord = et_conv.getText().toString();           
        Intent a = new Intent(AlphabetConversionMenu.this, AlphabetCompareClass.class);
        a.putExtra("key",checkWord);
        a.putExtras(word);
        startActivity(a);
    }
```

and in the onCreate of second activity

```
Bundle b;
b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
    mssg = b.getString("key");
```

Comment: hi sir. I get your code but one thing is i want also to query the images from my database to be pass too in the second activity.. @goonerdroid

Answer (score 1):

Select Statement will return the resultset object. If you want to compare it to the specific column then fetch the column name only. For comparing the string objects you can use String.compare method or simple == will be sufficient.

Comment: 1st get the comparison string from database then you will be able to compare the string

Comment: yes the problem is in the if statement that is in comments. i dont know how to put the table in it. Look at the comments in the second activity on the for loop side.

Comment: Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(Query, null); Cursor c1 = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
      int index = c1.getColumnIndex("imagename");
      
      //advance to the next record (first rec. if necessary)
      c1.moveToNext(); if(gotWord.getString("key").charAt(0)==c1.getString(index).charAt(0))

Comment: my problem now sir is that. the variable db and query, it cannot be resolved.. also the column name is in another class.

Comment: it has error on the part of the variable db and query @Mahesh Deshpande

Comment: is that because the database is in another class?

Comment: I dont think so. Database is for application not for single activity. Write seperate db class for database operations then use the class object to do your operations.

Answer (score 0):

In your first activity call like this :

```
Intent a = new Intent(AlphabetConversionMenu.this, AlphabetCompareClass.class);
a.putExtras("key", checkWord);
startActivity(a);
```

And in second activity get value like this

```
 get =  getIntent().getStringExtra("key","");  // here if no extra found then default "" return.
```